# Why is the proper "respond_to" format not getting called?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, controller, format, respond-to

I'm having a bit of an odd issue.  Really too odd to type out, but here goes.  Basically I have a controller that refuses to "respond_to" using javascript unless I assign my "chart.generate_xml" to a variable before the "respond_to" block like so:

```
  @xml = @chart.generate_xml(@begin_date,@end_date,1.hour)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js{
      render :update do |page|
        page.insert_html :bottom, "chart-div", @xml
        #page.insert_html :bottom, "chart-div", @chart.generate_xml(@begin_date,@end_date,1.hour)
      end
    }
```

If I remove the upper "@xml= …" portion and go with the lower "page.insert", the "format.js" section doesn't get called.  And if I try to force the format with "request.format = :js", I get the javascript returned as text.  I'm not doing anything special here in that method call, so I'm not sure why it would choose to respond any differently.

FWIW, the method that triggers this controller action is using JS to do so, so I'm confused as to why "format.js" isn't always getting called.  Thoughts?

Best.

Comment: can you post the code that invokes this action?

Comment: <%=link_to "<div class=\"matrix-img\"><img src='#{src}'/></div>",{:action => "view_chart", :id => chart.id}, :popup => ["#{chart.name.gsub(/\W/,'_')}", 'height = 650, width = 1000']%>

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue in your config/routes.rb file, as this can mess with the format.

Could you post this file and the header of the results from curl/wget?